# NodeJS put video streaming inside an element

Tags: node.js, dom, video-streaming

I am trying to create a list of link where if you click on one link a video stream starts. I can stream a video by using the code below but I am unable to create any other HTML element, apply CSS, etc. How do I embed this video stream inside, for example, a div and align it in the center below some text?

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

var port = 3001;
var host = "127.0.0.1";

var file_path = "my_video.mp4"

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var stat = fs.statSync(file_path);
  var total = stat.size;

  if (req.headers.range) {   // meaning client (browser) has moved the forward/back slider
                                         // which has sent this request back to this server logic ... cool
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    var partialstart = parts[0];
    var partialend = parts[1];

    var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
    var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;
    console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunksize);

    var file = fs.createReadStream(file_path, {start: start, end: end});
    res.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    file.pipe(res);

  } else {

    console.log('ALL: ' + total);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    fs.createReadStream(file_path).pipe(res);
  }
  // Does not work to create a h1 tag anywhere in the source document the user sees.
 if(res.url === '/') {
    res.end('<h1>Home</h1>');
 }
}).listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://" + host + ":" + port + "/");
```